# UInavigationbar background image does not resize correctly when orientation changes from landscape to portrait

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uinavigationbar

I am trying to set the background image of uinavigationbar for the portrait and landscape orientations. I am using the following code:

```
UIImage *navbarImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar"]
                            resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 9.0, 0, 9.0)];
UIImage *navbarLandscapeImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar-landscape"]
                                 resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 9.0, 0, 9.0)];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navbarImage
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navbarLandscapeImage
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone];
```

However, in the iOS5.1 simulator, when I change the orientation from portrait to landscape to portrait, the image that is used is navbar-landscape.png instead of navbar.png.

Here are some example images:

Portrait default:
[image]

Change to Landscape:
[image]

Change back to Portrait:
[image]

Does anyone have an idea of what the problem is here? I am not sure why the wrong image is getting used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it turns out that the problem is a bug in the simulator. I tried all of the solutions described above and none made a difference for when the problem gets resolved or not.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you setting this? You could try adding it to -(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews.

Comment: I am running this code in my application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in my appDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

You could just give one image both for landscape and potrait no need of having two different 
two different images
instead of giving UIEdgeinset like this

```
UIImage *navbarImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar"]
                        resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 9.0, 0, 9.0)];
```

you could  specify the top and bottom inset so that it will adjust height wise

```
UIImage *navbarImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navbar"]
                        resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(some value according the image u have, 9.0, some value according the image u have, 9.0)];
```

Answer (score -1):

In portrait mode: UINavigationBar Height = 44.

In landscape mode: UInavigationbar Height = 32

If you want them to be the same, you need to take their heights into account. For example:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    CGRect navframe = [[self.navigationController navigationBar] frame];
    navframe.size.height = 44.0f;
    [self.navigationController navigationBar].frame = navframe;
}
```

Comment: Hard coding sizes like this is a big no-no.